# What is the Mahalanobis Distance pf y relative to the distribution of x?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, vectors, mahalanobis-distance

I'm learning about the Mahalanobis Distance, and I had a question regarding an interesting problem:

> Let $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ be a Gaussian random vector with mean $\mu = \begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and covariance $P = \sigma^2 I$. Let $y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}$. What is the Mahalanobis Distance (MD) of $y$ relative to the distribution of $x$?

There are a few questions on StackExchange about the Mahalanobis Distance (such as: [How to calculate the Mahalanobis distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185947/how-to-calculate-the-mahalanobis-distance)), but I'm not sure I quite understand how to apply it in this circumstance at an abstract level. Furthermore, is the problem suggesting that the Mahalanobis distance is affected by the Probability Density function? Would anyone be able to assist me in solving this? Thanks for your time and help in advanced!

Comment: When it comes to Gaussian random vectors, the Mahalanobis Distance is just $(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)^{T}P^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)$. There's not much more to it than that. However, I've never heard of the Mahalanobis Distance of a random vector relative to the distribution of another random vector.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the square root of that? And I'm not sure if plugging directly into it will help answer the question about the relative distribution. That's where I'm confused

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's the square root of that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance#Normal_distributions The Mahalanobis Distance of $X$ to its mean vector $\mu$ follows a chi distribution, so if the distance of it to another constant vector $y$, then it should be a non-central chi distribution?

Comment: I'm not really sure? I don't know if I understand exactly why?